# Translate an equation into a code

Tags: matlab, loops, math, formula

Can you help me please translate this equation into a code?
[image: This is the equation]

I tried this code but its only the first part

```
theSum = sum(M(:, y) .* S(:, y) ./ (1 + K(:, y)))
```

Comment: Your first part look somewhat different, In your first part, what is `S(:,y)` ? `X(z,y) / L(z,y)`?

Comment: I think I wrote it wrong as I am a little bit confused

Comment: do you know what M(z,y)/K(z,y) means? Are M and K matricies? If these are matrices, then this only makes since if it implies elementwise division, but then the equation is ambiguous because I wouldn't know if I should interpret MXO and K^2 as normal matrix multiplication, or if they should be multiplied element-wise too ...

Comment: also, I just realised the (Xz,y) term at the end is ambiguous, in that it's not clear if it's part of the inner summation or the outer one. If this is from a paper, you might want to check the wording to see if it clarifies these questions.

Comment: Yes, they are matrices!

Comment: And the X is part of the inner summation

Comment: @Sassosamer actually, sorry, they are matrices but in the context of a summation of individual elements. (and X has a z index, so yes it belongs to the inner summation). So, no ambiguity, I'm just being silly. I wrote an answer below which does what you want in a vectorised manner. :)  Might be worth confirming it gives the same result as the for-loop version though, just to make doubly sure there's no typos etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: sorry, I was having a brainfart. The answer below makes no assumptions on the nature of M, K, etc, which is why I recommended functions like that. But they're clearly matrices. I'll make another answer, I'll leave this here for reference though in case it's useful**

I would start by making the `M`, `K`, `X`, `L`, and `O` expressions into simple functions, so that you can easily call them as `M(z,y)`, `X(z,y)` (or `X(z,j)` depending on the input you need ) etc.

Then you will convert each summation into a for loop and collect the result (you can think about vectorisation later, right now focus on translating the problem). The double summation is essentially a nested for loop, where the result of the inner loop is used in the outer one at each outer iteration.

So your end result should look something like:

```
Summation1 = 0;
for z = 1 : Z
  tmp = M(z,y) / K(z,y) * (X(z,y) / (1 + L(z,y));
  Summation1 = Summation1 + tmp;
end

Summation2 = 0;
for j = 1 : Y
  if j ~= y
    for z = 1 : Z
      tmp = (M(z,j) * X(z,j) * O(j)) / (K(z,j)^2 * (1 + L(z,j)) * X(z,y);
      Summation2 = Summation2 + tmp;
    end
  end
end

Result = Summation1 - Summation2;
```

(Btw, this assumes that all operations are on scalars. If `M(z,y)` outputs a vector, adjust for elementwise operations appropriately)

Comment: moving on to vectorisation, I'd still use functions, just adapt them accordingly to output vectors, and replace the for loops with simple operations on those vectors.

Comment: @Sassosamer: thank you for accepting this as an answer, but, out of curiosity, did you try my vectorized version below? This is still a nice general approach to the problem, but, for your specific example the vectorized approach below will be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** M, K, etc are all matrices, **and** all operations are expected to be element-wise, then this is a vectorised approach for this equation.

Left summation is

```
S1 = M(1:Z,y) ./ K(1:Z,y) .* X(1:Z,y) ./ (1 + L(1:Z,y));
S1 = sum(S1);
```

Right summation is (assuming (`O` is a horizontal vector)

```
S2 = M(1:Z, 1:Y) .* X(1:X, 1:Y) .* repmat(O(1:Y), [Z,1]) ./ ...
     (K(1:Z, 1:Y) .^ 2 .* (1 + L(1:Z, 1:Y))) .* X(1:Z, 1:Y);
S2(:,y) = [];   % remove the 'y' column from the matrix
S2 = sum(S2(:)); % add all elements
```

End result: `S1 - S2`

Comment: Dotn make another one, edit your one with both informations

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri ... SO asked me to confirm as well before posting; I felt this was one of those situations where a short second answer was preferable to a really long one with a long irrelevant first part, especially when the two confer very different information. Obviously I could delete my first answer altogether, but I thought it might be useful in its own right, so I left it for now.

Answer (score 0):

this is lambda version vectorized:

```
equation = @(y,M,K,X,L,O) ...
    sum(M(:,y)./K(:,y).*X(:,y)./(1+L(:,y))) ... 
    -sum(sum( ...
        bsxfun( ...
            @times ...
            ,M(:,[1:y-1,y+1:end]) ...
                .* X(:,[1:y-1,y+1:end]) ...
                .* O(:,[1:y-1,y+1:end]) ...
                ./ (K(:,[1:y-1,y+1:end]) .^ 2 ...
                .*(1+ L(:,[1:y-1,y+1:end]))) ...
            ,X(:,y) ...
        ) ...
    ));
%%% example:
y = 3;
Y = 5;
Z = 10;
M = rand(Y, Z);K = rand(Y, Z);X = rand(Y, Z);L = rand(Y, Z);O = rand(Y, Z);

equation(y,M,K,X,L,O)
```